# groupingBy to Collection Java8

Tags: java, generics, collections, lambda, java-8

My method looks like this:

```
 public static <T, E>  Map<E, List<T>> groupBy(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, E> function){
    return collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function::apply));
}
```

And it works, but i want my method to look like this:

```
public static <T, E>  Map<E, Collection<T>> groupBy(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, E> function){
    return collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function::apply));
}
```

And then it doesnt work, because groupingBy returns Map < E, List< T>>, not Map < E, Collection< T>>.

Of course i can do it like this:

```
   public static <T, E>  Map<E, Collection<T>> groupBy(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, E> function){
    return (Map<E, Collection<T>>) (Map) collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function::apply));
}
```

but I don't like this solution. Also method declaration:

```
    public static <T, E>  Map<E, Collection<T>> groupBy(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, E> function)
```

HAS TO stay that way (that was part of the task). So is there any better solutions than casting? I know there is second version of *groupingBy* which as a second paramether it takes Collector which can change type of the map which *groupingBy* returns. However I don't know how to use it. 
There is *Collectors.toCollection()*, but I think it will still be returning some implementation of Collection, not Collection itself.

There is also possibility of writing my custom Collector, following this link:
http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/07/introduction-to-writing-custom.html

but i don't know how to use it with Collection.

I would really apprieciate your help, thanks :)

Comment: Of course toCollection returns some implementation of Collection. Collection is an interface, so it doesn't have an implementation. When using toCollection, you can choose which implementation to use, but the returned type would be `Collection`.

Comment: It is nonsensical to pass `function::apply` to a method which expects a function. Just use `function`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public static <T, E>  Map<E, Collection<T>> groupBy(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, E> function){
    return collection.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function,
                                                    Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
}
```

This would produce an `ArrayList` instance for each value in the `Map`. You can choose other collections if you wish (just change `ArrayList::new`).

Comment: I know you just copied it from the question but I recommend replacing `function::apply` with `function` before other coders start copying this code fragment and useless wrapping of functions within another function becomes a common trope…

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the type of collector and also the type of Map:

```
public static <T, E> Map<E, Collection<T>> groupBy(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, E> function){
    return collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function::apply, HashMap::new,Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
}
```